# Can I edit form1.ui.h outside of qt editor?

Tags: qt

The Title says everything. I'm pretty new to qt and don't really like the editor it provides.

`vim form1.ui.h` doesn't work.

Comment: "Doesn't work", how? What happens and what do you expect?

Comment: It opens a blank file opposed to the file shown in qt Designer @Andy

Comment: @Awalrod most likely it creates file with name `ui_form1.h`

Comment: Did you remember to *build* the project? That .h file is generated by *uic* tool when building the project.

Comment: Also, the GUI Designer takes some time getting used to, and learning the right way to do things, and having the right attitude (don't fight with it, roll with it ;-). With that it's quite usable. If that's not your thing, use QML, or write widget UI by hand in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you mean header file *generated* from your `.ui` file. Well, since it's *generated* - editing it is not very good idea, because it will be regenerated from `.ui` each time you build you program.

But you obviously can:

- Edit `.ui` file with any xml/text editor. Though it's really strange and wouldn't win much over using designer itself.
- Do not use `.ui` files at all - encapsulate creation of desired interfaces in your own classes containing simple C++/Qt code. That way actually is not that bad if you're experienced with Qt layout/widget system and know what you wish to achieve. Because there's no any kind of pixel hunting needs to be done in designer and placing things in appropriate way may actually be done even in more structured manner in code than in form creation. Though as I said it's not the way for everyone and you have to be accurate, also it's better separate interface code from other functionality.

Comment: That doesn't open the file I want

Comment: After fooling around a bit, I think not using the designer is best. It's easy enough to use PyQt without the designer. I might come back to it if I want to try it with C++. Thank you!